# How can I improve this paginated do while async await GET request in Javascript (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios, do-while

I am learning JavaScript (Node.js - using the Pipedream platform). I have been writing scripts to help automate some little tasks in my day to day work.

I am creating one that generates a report on recent interactions with clients.

As part of this I am using axios to get "engagements" from the Hubspot API (basically a list of identifiers I will use in later requests).

The API returns paginated responses. I have encountered pagination previously and understand the principle behind it, but have never written a script to handle it. This is my first.

It works. But I feel it could be improved. Below I've commented how I've approached it.

The endpoint returns up to 100 values 'per page' along with a `"hasMore":true` flag and an `"offset":987654321` value which can be passed as a query parameter in subsequent requests (if hasMore === true).

Example API response:

```
{"results":[1234,1235,1236],"hasMore":true,"offset":987654321}
```

My code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
//function to get each page of data
async function getAssoc(req){
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://api.hubapi.com/${req}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${auths}`,
        },
      };
      return await axios(options);
}
//declare array in which to store all 'associations'
const assocs = [];
//store the ID that I get in an earlier step
const id = vid;
//declare variable in which to temporarily store each request response data
var resp;
//declare query parameter value, initially blank, but will be assigned a value upon subsequent iterations of do while
var offset = '';
do {
  //make request and store response in resp variable
  resp = await getAssoc(`crm-associations/v1/associations/${id}/HUBSPOT_DEFINED/9?offset=${offset}`);
  //push the results into my 'assocs' (associations) array
  resp.data.results.forEach(element => assocs.push(element));
  //store offset value for use in next iteration's request
  offset = resp.data.offset;
} while (resp.data.hasMore); //hasMore will be false when there's no more records to request

return assocs;
```

I feel it could be improved because:

1. The DO WHILE loop, I believe, is making sequential requests. Is parallel a better/faster/more efficient option? *(EDIT Thanks @Evert - of course I cannot make parallel requests because of the offset!)*
2. I'm re-assigning new values to **var**s instead of using **const**s which seems simple and intuitive in my beginner's mind, but I don't understand a better way in this instance.
3. I would welcome any feedback or suggestions on how I can improve this for my own learning.

Thank you in advance for your time and any assistance you can offer.

Comment: You probably can't parallize this because you need to know the offset from the previous page to know the next page url. Changing variables is fine, but use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thank you @Evert - that makes perfect sense - thanks!

Comment: I would go with a local state first to store the previous and next offset along with an array of the actual data and ofc update it upon every response. Then after that I would do a recursive function to keep calling itself as long as the `state.hasMore` is still true.

Comment: Thank you @JefferyThaGintoki I have never used a recursive function before. I am researching how to apply this concept now.

Comment: Code looks just fine (but I'm missing a function declaration, it seems incomplete?), but asking for feedback on working code is off-topic. You might want to ask at [codereview.SE] instead (but check their guidelines first)

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about Code Review, @Bergi - thanks for that!

Comment: @Paul recursion is not necessarily better here. It might be a bit shorter, but can be more difficult to debug. Your solution is fine and at most doing a recursive version is a subjective opinion.